# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource resolver is already closed. error for JUNIT5 in aem servlet

Tags: aem, junit5

I am getting an exception when running a JUNIT5 code for a AEM servlet where the resource resolver is fecthed from AEM context and used, JUNIT gives proper response, but at the end am getting

javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Session is logged out / not live.java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource resolver is already closed.

```
at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.checkClosed(ResourceResolverImpl.java:202)
```

Comment: can you post the unit test which produces this error?

Comment: were you able resolve this issue , I am facing same issue, while writing junit aem test cases.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue for the second time. for the first use case, it was working fine. So, I had to return resource resolver two times and session as well and it started working.

```
when(resourceResolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(params)).thenReturn(resource.getResourceResolver(), resourceResolver);
when(resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class)).thenReturn(mockSession,session);
```

Had to initiate session and resource resolver two times.